# tfs2015: User Capacity Database Storage

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, scrum

I'm looking to create a more robust user capacity report, I love the one included in the Portal interface within TFS2015 U1, however I can't find a larger version that can be handed to management or stakeholders other than the column view on the Board.

Is this per-iteration data stored within the SQL Database? If so, where?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TFS REST API to build your own capacity report by calling the [Get a team's capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/work/capacity#Getateamscapacity) and [Get a team member's capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/work/capacity#Getateammemberscapacity) APIs.